# Is UART a Mealy machine?

Tags: uart

I'm learning the basics of UART and its features. When I look at published state diagrams for UART then it looks like a Mealy machine. Is it a Mealy machine or did I misunderstand? My understanding is that UART is a FSM type Mealy.

Comment: A Mealy machine has no registers, only the current state. Is this also true for the UART state diagram? (Please show it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term "Mealy machine" (or "Moore Machine" or whatever other terms you have at your disposal) is rather a *way of looking at* systems or way a system *can* be implemented.

I.e. asking whether some generic system (here: UART) *is* this or that machine doesn't make sense. It *can* be seen and implemented as Mealy machine but it can also be seen or implemented as Moore machine or as Turing machine or as register machine or as stack machine or...

One way may be more or less appropriate but many are possible.

So if you ask whether something *is* a Mealy machine that something must be a *way of how* a system is described or implemented (the diagrams you are referring to); but we don't know what diagrams you are talking about.